# Filter blacklisted data

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a set of mobile numbers in a column (list-1)

I have another set of blacklisted mobile numbers in another column (list-2)

How can I make a 3rd column (list-3) that removed the blacklisted mobile numbers from the list-1?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

With List-1 in column A, List-2 in column B, use this in column C, starting in row 2 (assuming row 1 has labels)

=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A2,B:B,0)),A2,"")

Copy down. Copy and paste the results with paste special > Values, then sort the data in column C and remove the blanks.

Comment: If this answers your question, please mark it as the answer so that other people can see that there is a solution.